# Handle duplicates when inserting objects to core data entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

In my application, I'm downloading data from web service with pagination. Output is a json array of dictionaries.

Now, I am saving the output json array in core data. So, my problem is, every time calls the saveInCoreData: method with the result array, it creates duplicate objects in the data base. How can i check for an object and update or replace the object if its already exists?
**myId** is a uniq key.

```
// save in coredata
+ (void) saveInCoreData:(NSArray *)arr{

// get manageObjectContext
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

if(arr != nil && arr.count > 0) {

    for(int i=0; i < arr.count; i++){

        SomeEntity *anObj = [NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SomeEntity"
                                inManagedObjectContext:context];


        anObj.description = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
        anObj.count = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[[arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"count"] integerValue]];

        // Relationship
        OtherEntity *anOtherObject = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OtherEntity"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
        creatorDetails.companyName = [[[arrTopics objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"creator"] objectForKey:@"companyName"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose you are adding Photo with attributes, name, id, date taken, location etc. Let "id " be the property which is unique in all the Photos, if that is the case simply Select your Photo Entity in xcdatamodeld and in Inspector windows in Constraints tab, enter that attribute name, thats all, now when you you perform save, Core Data will verify it's uniqueness and you will get only one instance of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to avoid duplicates is to fetch all the objects you already have, and avoid processing them when iterating over the results.

*Get the topicIds from the results:*

```
NSArray *topicIds = [results valueForKeyPath:@"topicId"];
```

*Fetch existing topics with these topicIds:*

```
NSFetchRequest *request = ...;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@",
                                 @"topicId", topicIds];
NSArray *existingTopics = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

*Get the existing topicIds:*

```
NSArray *existingTopicIds = [existingTopics valueForKeyPath:@"topicId"];
```

*Process the results:*

```
for (NSDictionary *topic in results) {
    if ([existingTopicIds containsObject:topic[@"topicId"]]) {
        // Update the existing topic if you want, or just skip.

        continue;
    }

    ...
}
```

Attempting to fetch each existing topic individually, within the processing loop, will be very inefficient in terms of time.  The tradeoff is more memory usage, but as you are only getting 20 objects at a time, this should be a complete non-issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer